# Combining probabilities of simultaneous related events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I will use a sports analogy to give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

There are two football/soccer teams. Team A and Team B and each of these teams have a probability of win - draw - loss for their next game that is based on their previous games of the season. These previous games consist of playing various teams and not against each other.

Team A has a win - draw - loss probability of 60% - 15% - 25%

Team B has a win - draw - loss probability of 30% - 20% - 50%

The next game is Team A vs Team B and this is where I'm confused.

Team A has a probability to win of 60% but Team B has a probability to lose of 50%. These two probabilities have to occur together - if Team A wins then Team B has to lose, if Team B wins then Team A has to lose and if Team A draws then Team B also has to draw.

What I've been doing is multiplying the probabilities together and then normalizing the probability to [0,1] scale.

Example:

((.60 * .50) + (.25 * .30) + (.20 * .15)) / sum of all probabilities
(.30 + .075 + .03) = .405

Next to estimate the probability of the various scenarios I would do the following:
.30 / .405 = .74, meaning the probability of Team A winning and Team B losing is 74%.
.075 / .405 = .185 meaning the probability of a Team B winning and Team A losing is 18.5%
.03 / .405 = .074 meaning the probability of a draw is 7.4%

Is this the correct way to combine probabilities of events that are required to happen simultaneously?

Comment: There is not a single correct answer.  Here is a point to consider for your suggestion:  suppose every team was equally skilled and every match had win-draw-loss probabilities of $40\%:20\%:40\%$ for both teams: would your method then produce $40\%:20\%:40\%$ for a particular match?

Comment: I see what you're saying. In your example it seems as though averaging or adding the probabilities would return the correct probability. I would assume averaging would be a better method since adding would only be used if only one event can happen, from my understanding. My reasoning in my original post would actually return 44% : 11% : 44%. Is this scenario more of a judgement call rather than a probability axiom?